# Get funding for a research period abroad while being a PhD student

Tags: funding, abroad

I am a second year PhD student in computer science, in Europe. For a number of reasons, when beginning the PhD I decided to keep on with my previous job, doing an unfunded part-time PhD.

Now, I have decided that I would like to continue with academic career, and I would like to spend a part of my third year in a foreign university, ideally in the US.

The issue is that I can not do this with my own money (that I don't have :) ), as to do this I would have to leave my job, for sure. So, currently I don't have any funding.

So my question: there exist some kind of funding to cover this kind of research periods abroad? And also, where to look? My own university, the European union or the future hosting institution?

Comment: which is your country? Many, but not all, EU countries have "mobility" scholarships exactly for these reasons.

Comment: @PsySp I am in Madrid, Spain

Comment: Would something like this help? http://www.european-funding-guide.eu/scholarship/2394-mobility-scholarship-masterdoctorate